# doxygen - using ".." causes unexpected token TK_EOF

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I have directory tree:

```
myproj/
    doc/installation.md
    tools/install/installation_ubu.md
    tools/install/installation_macos.md
    tools/install/installation_msys2.md
    Doxyfile
```

The installation.md file contains these lines:

```
* Ubuntu: [installation_ubu](../tools/install/installation_ubu.md)
* MacOS: [installation_macos](../tools/install/installation_macos.md)
* Windows MSYS2: [installation_msys2](../tools/install/installation_msys2.md)
```

When I run doxygen I get:

```
doc/installation.md:6: warning: unexpected token TK_EOF as the argument of ref
doc/installation.md:7: warning: unexpected token TK_EOF as the argument of ref
doc/installation.md:8: warning: unexpected token TK_EOF as the argument of ref
```

In Ubuntu I'm using:

```
$ doxygen --version
1.8.17
```

Looked it up on the net. Looks like there are similar problems with these links. They were fixed in previous versions of doxygen but I'm still getting them.

Rolled over to MacOS and got a later version:

```
$ doxygen --version
1.9.8
```

Still get the same warnings.

The reason I'd like to keep these is they work correctly under Pycharm (uses pandoc).

Anything I can do to fix this for doxygen?

---

**Update:** I tried getting rid of the ".md" suffix:

```
* Ubuntu: [installation_ubu](../tools/install/installation_ubu)
* MacOS: [installation_macos](../tools/install/installation_macos)
* Windows MSYS2: [installation_msys2(../tools/install/installation_msys2)
```

- no warnings
- doxygen now includes the file contents in the generated PDF.
- the generated HTML fails: clicking on the links shows "404 Not Found". Note: that it failed with ".md" suffixes.The HTML showed just text.
- pandoc (in Pycharm) doesn't work any more

---

**Update:**
I start doxygen at the root, ie.from myproj directory

output of doxygen -x:

```
$ doxygen -x Doxyfile
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'CREATE_SUBDIRS_LEVEL' at line 98, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'PYTHON_DOCSTRING' at line 255, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'NUM_PROC_THREADS' at line 493, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'RESOLVE_UNNAMED_PARAMS' at line 564, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'SHOW_HEADERFILE' at line 638, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'WARN_IF_INCOMPLETE_DOC' at line 856, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'WARN_LINE_FORMAT' at line 896, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'INPUT_FILE_ENCODING' at line 937, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'FORTRAN_COMMENT_AFTER' at line 1150, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'HTML_COLORSTYLE' at line 1361, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'DOCSET_FEEDURL' at line 1462, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'FULL_SIDEBAR' at line 1673, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'OBFUSCATE_EMAILS' at line 1704, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'HTML_FORMULA_FORMAT' at line 1715, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'MATHJAX_VERSION' at line 1752, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'DOT_COMMON_ATTR' at line 2452, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'DOT_EDGE_ATTR' at line 2461, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'DOT_NODE_ATTR' at line 2469, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'DOT_UML_DETAILS' at line 2537, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'DOT_WRAP_THRESHOLD' at line 2546, file doxyfile_master
warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'DIR_GRAPH_MAX_DEPTH' at line 2619, file doxyfile_master
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
PROJECT_NAME           = "myproj"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 0.0.1
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "myproj"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./out/doc
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = YES
INHERIT_DOCS           = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 0
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = YES
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = YES
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = YES
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = YES
QUIET                  = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
WARN_LOGFILE           = out/doxygen.txt
INPUT                  = .
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.tcl \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = ./pytest_cache \
                         ./dist \
                         ./out \
                         ./venv \
                         ./pf* \
                         ./*.egg-info \
                         ./ut \
                         ./ver \
                         ./tools \
                         ./sample/test.py \
                         ./sample/main.py \
                         ./lib/build_info.py
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = pf_* \
                         test_tp*.py
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 100
```

---

**Update:** I moved these files to the local directory:

```
* Ubuntu: [installation_ubu](installation_ubu)
* MacOS: [installation_macos](installation_macos)
* Windows MSYS2: [installation_msys2(installation_msys2)
```

- no more warnings
- doxygen PDF works okay.
- generated HTML works okay
- pandoc (in Pycharm) does not work

If I add the ".md" suffix:

```
* Ubuntu: [installation_ubu](installation_ubu.md)
* MacOS: [installation_macos](installation_macos.md)
* Windows MSYS2: [installation_msys2(installation_msys2.md)
```

- get the 3 warnings
- doxygen PDF works okay
- the generated HTML works okay
- pandoc (in Pycharm) works okay

Comment: Please also specify the settings different from the default doxygen settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) and also mention the directory from where you start the doxygen command.

Comment: @albert  see above.

Comment: In the `EXCLUDE` part I see `./tools` this also removes  the `*.md` on the `tools/install` directory from processing and thus no links are possible.

Comment: @albert My bad! Thank you for seeing that! I updated the question. the PDF and HTML work fine whether I have the .md or not. The pandoc only works with the .md. The warnings do show up with the ".md" but like I said, it works. If you post an answer I can give it a checkmark.